# tx-news: use a main category in the link / speaking url

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, realurl, tx-news, viewhelper

I am developing a site which has **two main area's** which I destinguish as **two main system categories.**

I use the latest version of **tx-news** (5.3.2) for articles and I assign them firstly to one of the two main system categories, and then to a specif category which exists for both main categories ...

in the frontpage I list a limited number of the latest articles, not limited by **any** category

1. how can I create links that considers the choice of the main category?
2. how can this show up in the
   Url: *`mydomain.com/category-1/article`* or
   *`mydomain.com/category-2/article`*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy the `LinkViewViewHelper` of EXT:news to a custom extension and add the category uid then to the link. After that it is possible to rewrite the id with realurl to the title.

Comment: Can you point to any more information/code example, I get the idea but am still in the dark what to do exactly ...

Comment: `namespace Vendor\NewsExtension\ViewHelpers;` or leave yours ... `class LinkViewHelper extends \GeorgRinger\News\ViewHelpers\LinkViewHelper` and add only ... etc., I know this is pretty basic to you ...

Comment: i'd like to extend your `LinkViewHelper` otherwise I need to re-write all the templates using the custom extensions namespace and all the `n:link` to `my:link` ...